# Mockito failing to work with predicate function

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have the following test:

```
  @Test
  public void testListIntersectionByRoleIsEmpty() {
    when(sfa.getRequesterGroups()).thenReturn(testRoles);
    when(shareableMetacard.getAccessGroups()).thenReturn(mockedRoleSet);
    assertTrue(sfa.sharedByGroup().test(shareableMetacard));
  }
```

This is testing the following code:

```
  @VisibleForTesting
  Predicate<Share> sharedByGroup() {
    return metacard ->
        !metacard
            .getAccessGroups()
            .stream()
            .filter(getRequesterGroups()::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .isEmpty();
  }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No methods matching the name(s) test were found in the class hierarchy of class java.lang.Object.

I've tried almost everything possible to get this working..

### Declarations

- `sfa = spy(new SearchFormsApplication(catalogFramework, templateTransformer, endpointUtil));`
- `@org.mockito.Mock Share shareableMetacard;`

Comment: I've had problems in the past with powermock and Java 8 features such as streams. Perhaps this is a powermock issue rather than a Mockito issue? What version of powermock do you have?

Comment: Think there was some versioning issues. Fixed to 1.7.3 and now it's good

Comment: Dont put up *segments* of your code. Instead, create a *complete* but minimal [mcve]!